# How to set the line width of line in fpdf uniquely throughout the document

Tags: php

I have line generating function in fpdf which will need to  generate line with unique line width for all the titles throughout the document. Here is my code.

```
function createLine($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2){  
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.1);
    $this->Line($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);    
}
```

But the problem is, it does not generate line with specified line width or bold.
Here is the code how the function is called.

```
$x = $this->GetX();
$y = $this->GetY();
$this->createLine($x, $y,200,$y);
$this->Cell(60,5,'',0,2,'');
$this->SetFont('Courier','B',$fontSizelarge);// Title is bold

$this->Cell(128,5,$this->fieldTitles[1],0,2,'L');// Title
$this->SetFont('Courier','','7');                // Content  is not bold. 
$this->MultiCell(128,5,$ajaxResult['dis'] ,0,2,''); //Description Data
```

I have tried using different values for line width but it does not working.

Comment: Your script works for me. 
Are you sure you don't get an error somewhere (and this is why your pdf is not updated)? Your line might be overwritten by something else. I suggest you comment out everything below `$this->createLine(...)` and rerun your script.